# reducer not called by driver in mapreduce wordcount program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

```
   package com.delhi;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class UppercaseDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length !=2){
            System.out.printf("Two parameters are required- <input dir> <output dir>n");
        return -1;}


    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job=Job.getInstance(conf); 
    job.setJobName("uppercase");
    job.setJarByClass(UppercaseDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(UpperCaseMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(UpperCaseReduce.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job,new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));
    //job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return success ?0:1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitcode = ToolRunner.run(new UppercaseDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitcode);
    }

}
```

This is driver program.

next is reducer program:

```
package com.delhi;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class UpperCaseReduce extends Reducer< Text,LongWritable, Text, LongWritable>{



    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> value,
        org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      int sum=0;
      System.out.println("how +++++++++++++++++" + key);
      for(LongWritable st: value){
          sum = (int) (sum + st.get());

      }
      System.out.println("how +++++++++++++++++" + key);
    context.write(key, new LongWritable(sum));
}

}
```

next is mapper program:

```
package com.delhi;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class UpperCaseMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, LongWritable>{

@Override
protected void map(Object key, Text value,
        org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    String arr[] = line.split(" ");
    System.out.println("hello++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    for(String st: arr){
    //context.write(new Text(st.toUpperCase().trim()),new LongWritable(1));
    context.write(new Text(st),new LongWritable(1));
    }
}
}
```

from the already exist solution I find it out that in this type of problem outputkeyclass and outputvalueclass should match with reducer.I think I takecare  that part properly.I my case @Override for reduce is not working.I am using hadoop 7.2.3. I try to use trim function also.Problem is wordcount is not happening.I is giving me only "word 1", for any word in output file.
I started with different problem and I ended like this.Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Its really hard trying to work out what your question is. Are you getting an error? Is a reducer running or not? Ask one question and make it clear what you are having issues with.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting this output:a       1
a       1
file    1
file    1
file1   1
for     1
is      1
is      1
is      1
So, simple word count is not working.My question is why? I think reducer is not working.

Comment: Please edit the question to make it more readable. Start with the problem, then post the code, and then add any details you wish. Add your previous comment as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you add an `@Override` annotation to your `reduce` method you get an error:

> Method does not override method from its superclass

So you have a problem where the method signature doesn't match the one in `Reducer`.

You have:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> value,
                   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
```

If you change it to:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> value, Context context)
```

The error goes away. Since your `reduce` method wasn't overriding any methods it wouldnt have been called and it would have used an Identity reduce which matches your output.